# Combine two columns with if condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two columns with data which overlap for some entries (and are almost similar when they do).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                  {'x':[2.1,3.1,5.4,1.9,np.nan,4.3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'y':[np.nan,np.nan,5.3,1.9,3.2,4.2,9.1,7.8,4.1]
                  }
                 )
```

I want the result to be a column 'xy' which contains the average of x and y when they both have values and x or y when only one of them has a value like this:

```
df['xy']=[2.1,3.1,5.35,1.9,3.2,4.25,9.1,7.8,4.1]
```

Comment: `df['xy'] = df[['x','y']].mean(1)`

Comment: Did you try anything whatsoever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

**Solution**

```
df['xy'] = df[['x','y']].mean(axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
print(df.to_string())

     x    y    xy
0  2.1  NaN  2.10
1  3.1  NaN  3.10
2  5.4  5.3  5.35
3  1.9  1.9  1.90
4  NaN  3.2  3.20
5  4.3  4.2  4.25
6  NaN  9.1  9.10
7  NaN  7.8  7.80
8  NaN  4.1  4.10
```